# Des synonymes (amusants et créatifs) de « il y a un problème » ?

Tags: expressions, synonymes, humour

> On pointait tous les deux une direction différente, il y avait donc un problème.
>
> (...) je pense qu’il y a un problème.

pourraient être tournés en :

> il y a des choses qui clochent / tournent pas rond

Vos tournures, qu’elles soient officielles ou créatives, sérieuses ou amusantes (et même locale ou personnelle) sont les bienvenues !

Comment: "Y a une couille dans le potage" en est une

Comment: "Houston ? Nous avons un problème."

Comment: "quelque chose capote"  / "tout a capoté !"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**un problème:**

> un blème.
>
> un lézard.
>
> un loup. (quelque chose de caché)
>
> le mistigri. (problème plus ou moins identifié, que l'on se repasse, ou qui apparaît et reparaît tel un chat ...)
>
> le bâton *merdeux*. (un problème déjà identifié, dont on ne veut pas, et que l'on tente de repasser à quelqu'un d'autre ...)
>
> une cagade. (approximatif: raté monumental et ridicule)
>
> un grain de sable. (un petit défaut qui compromet une opération)
>
> un truc (assez vague ...)
>
> un hic
>
> un couac
>
> un schmilblick
>
> une *merde* (familier)
>
> Il y a *maldonne* (problème sur ce qu'on a fait, qu'on est en train de faire, ou de convenir avec d'autres personnes ...)

**Une erreur:**

> une coquille (résultat d'une action mal effectuée)
>
> une boulette (idem)
>
> un défaut
>
> un raté
>
> un ratage
>
> un viandage
>
> un foirage

**Quelque chose qui ne va pas:**

> Qui débloque.
>
> Qui *déconne*.
>
> Qui déraille.
>
> Qui ne tourne pas rond.
>
> Qui cloche.
>
> Qui part en vrille. (sens approximatif: qui devient hors de contrôle, comme les suivants:)
>
> Qui part en sucette.
>
> Qui part en quenouille.
>
> Qui part en *live*.

Comment: On peut rajouter "une coquille"

Comment: @Charly - merci

Comment: Notons que la coquille convient particulièrement aux erreurs typographiques, et que cagade est je pense un régionalisme du sud de la France.

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina excellent, merci !

Comment: Ah c'est intéressant, je ne connaissais pas "partir en quenouille". J'ai toujours entendu dire "partir en couille" -  je me demande si l'expression n'est pas partie de "quenouille".

Comment: @Wof, hélas oui: proximité phonétique. L'expression est sexiste à l'origine: tomber aux mains des femmes, laisser à l'abandon: voir là : http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/quenouille

Answer (score 4):

Pour compléter la réponse assez complète mais difficilement exhaustive de Guillaume :

- Un couac
- Un foirage (familier)
- Un souci
- Une couille (dans le pâté) - vulgaire

Et en Belgique francophone : un stûût

Comment: merci + 1 - j'ai emprunté couac et foirage, particulièrement efficaces !

Comment: +1 pour le stûût